# Overlapping Japanese content rendered by Jfreechart in pdf

Tags: localization, pdf-generation, itext, jfreechart

We are using Jfreechart along with iText for generating pdf reports. For Japanese, we realized that in the rendered content for the graph legend, characters don't have any spaces between them. They basically overlap which makes it hard to read.

Do we need to use any special encoding?

Attached are images for expected and actual(generated by jfreechart), in that order

[image: Expected]

[image: Generated by iText]

Below is a snippet of the graph generated with the legend

[image]

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117194).

Answer (score 1):

According to the PDF specification, a CIDFont dictionary contains an optional dictionary called DW and an optional array called W. DW is the default width for glyphs. If not set, it defaults to 1000.

The W array describes individual widths for characters in the font (if not specified they default to the value of DW). For many Japanese fonts, I've seen the value set to lower than 1000, but in this case it might be too low.

You can take a look at these values using Acrobat's "preflight>browse internal structure" tool. If these seem off, you make be using the wrong encoding. Setting encoding to "UniJIS-UCS2-H" should help resolve this issue.